# Oracle sql combination

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table with this result (just for example, actually it has more records):

```
31.3.2020   A  1
30.4.2020   A  2
31.3.2020   B  1
30.4.2020   C  3
```

Is possible to add there empty missing values by sql?
In this case:

```
30.4.2020   B  0
31.3.2020   C  0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `cross join` to generate the rows and then `left join` to bring in the existing values:

```
select  c1.col1, c2.col2, coalesce(col3, 0) as col3
from (select distinct col1 from t) c1 cross join
     (select distinct col2 from t) c2 left join
     t
     on t.col1 = c1.col1 and t.col2 = c2.col2;
```

This returns all rows (including those with existing values).  You can add `where t.col1 is null` to get only the additional rows.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
select col1, col2,
case when (col3 is null or col3 = '') then 0 else col3 as col3
from table;
```

You can use below if you don't have any empty strings,

```
select col1, col2,
case when nvl(col3, 0) as col3
from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `anti join` and `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
SQL> with your_data (col1, col2, col3) as
  2  (select to_date('31.3.2020','dd.mm.rrrr'),   'A',  1 from dual union all
  3  select to_date('30.4.2020','dd.mm.rrrr'),   'A',  2 from dual union all
  4  select to_date('31.3.2020','dd.mm.rrrr'),   'B',  1 from dual union all
  5  select to_date('30.4.2020','dd.mm.rrrr'),   'C',  3 from dual)
  6  -- your query starts from here
  7  select distinct t1.col1, t2.col2, 0 as col3
  8  from your_data t1 join your_data t2 on t1.col1 <> t2.col1
  9  where not exists
 10  (select 1 from your_data t where t2.col2 = t.col2 and t1.col1 = t.col1)
 11  order by t1.col1, t2.col2;

COL1      C       COL3
--------- - ----------
31-MAR-20 C          0
30-APR-20 B          0

SQL>
```

Then `UNION` it with your data.